# Drag/Drop calculation tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am building a "product configurator". What I am trying to do is that when a product is dragged from a list and dropped in the "customizable" area the total price change. So far, I have done this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidePanel">
     <ul id="list-two" class="linked">
     <li id="PTB1" data-price="45"><img src="PTB%201.jpg"></li>
     <li id="PTB2" data-price="55"><img src="PTB%202.jpg"></li>
     <li id="PTB3" data-price="67"><img src="PTB%203.jpg"></li>
     <li id="PTB1" data-price="50"><img src="PTB%204.jpg"></li>
 </ul>


 <ul id="list-three" class="linked">
     <li><img src="Screen%201.jpg"</li>
     <li><img src="Screen%202.png"></li>
     <li><img src="Refills.jpg"></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<p class="total">TOTAL $</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var totalCost = 0;
var basket = []



$(function() {
$("#list-one").sortable({
    revert: true,
    beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).data("lastItem", ui.item);
    },
    receive: function(e, source) {
        basket.push($(".linked li").data('price'));
            for (var i = 0; i < basket.length; i++) {
            totalCost += basket[i] << 0;
        $("p.total").html("Total: $"+totalCost)
            }

    }
});

$(".linked li").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#list-one",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});

$("ul, li, img").disableSelection();
});
```

The problem I have is that whenever I drag and drop a new product on the customizable area, it only/always take the data-price of the first product of the list (45) and it also seems that the calculation is not happening correctly. However, I would like to target the data-price of the dragged/dropped product.

Any idea on how to fix that (or improve it) ?

Comment: `the calculation is not happening correctly`... wait, why are you using `<< 0` when you add the price to the total amount? are you using it to remove the decimals from it?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code just a tad so you don't have to work with '<<', which I'm not entirely convinced you should be using in this case.

```
receive: function(e, source) {
    var item = parseInt(source.item[0].dataset.price);
    basket.push(item);
    totalCost = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < basket.length; i++) {
        totalCost += basket[i];
        $("p.total").html("Total: $"+totalCost)
      }
}
```